# Как писать онлайн приложение?

Tags: android

написал приложение под андроид в целом все хорошо, но все же приложение задумано чтобы пользователь скачал открыл нажал "получить" и получил промокод доступный на данный момент, но есть проблема приложение (не считая промокоды и рекламу) автономное, т.е. чтобы добавить новую позицию с бесплатными промокодами, нужно обязательно обновить приложение в маркете, так вот вопрос: как правильно написать код приложения, чтобы без обновления приложения в маркете добавлять новые позиции и убирать кончившиеся (как пример что-то похожее на приложение Pepper.ru)?

P.S. сайт не имеется и не планируется, исключительно приложение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пишите web-сервис с удаленной СУБД, либо смотрите в сторону Firebase

Comment: с Firebase как раз работаю, в БД промокоды лежат, но если не трудно можно подробнее объяснить как с помощью Firebase настроить?

Comment: а как вы данные берете? Ведь вы отправляете запрос к базе данных и получаете ответ.

Comment: Отправляю запрос на получение значения из массива в бд, но как целый интерфейс? Можно ссылку на пример какой-нибудь, может на github'e есть?

Comment: Я с Firebase не работал. Использовал только систему Notification. Я просто не представляю в чем у вас трудности. Вот вы хотите добавить новую позицию. Что это? Новый элемент, наподобии уже существующего, откуда вы на данный момент получаете промокод?

Comment: вот, в вопросе я добавил интерфейс приложения, позиция т.е. как Papa Johns, Origin Access такого типа позиция, то есть Папа джонс кончатся его убрать из приложения, появится другой промокод добавить его, и т.д. а промокод получаю из Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Ну вот у вас 2 карточки, вы должны возвращать список из карточек (в вашем случае их только 2). Каждая карточка состоит из названия, id, ссылки на изображение, и описания, время начала работы карточки и время конца, можно еще и цвет.
В приложении получаете этот список и проверяете текущая дата лежит между началом и концом, если да, то добавляете в адаптер RecyclerView (или любой другой), иначе нет (так как или уже закончилась или еще не началась), и все, теперь вам их даже из базы данных на firebase не нужно удалять, просто добавляете новые записи и все. И приложение не нужно обновлять

Comment: Вроде понял, спасибо, за развернутый ответ)